# I want to keep the position of ADD TO CART button right above the bottom of of grid . But its going down when the name of the book exceeds to 2 rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

[Screen shot of my grid items of one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN7wU.png)I want to keep the position of ADD TO CART button right above the bottom of of grid . But its going down when the name of the book exceeds to 2 rows. please resolve the issue even if the name of one item is larger than the other item's names in the same row but the button should remain 5 to 10px above the grid item bottom. Thank You,i tried bottom:0; but it also did not work...

```
    .items-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(20rem, 1fr));
     
    }

    .item-box {
        margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #E6E0DE;
        align-items: flex-end;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px rgba(47,47,47,0.40);
        height:95%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be something in your html file that's causing it bump down a bit. In the case if all the other boxes are using the same CSS code. You can show your html file so I can take a look.

Comment: thank you for your comment. i am filling the boxes dynamically from JS and as i mentioned that the buttons are bumped down due to the Name of the books which are not the same for all items ... the shorter names's item's Buttons are slighter upper than the buttons in the items having larger names ie(book name exceeds to two rows )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh shoot. You are right I miss read it. This seems like a flexbox issue. I am new to coding and don't know JS. Sorry I might not be able to help you. Have you tried adding align-self: flex-end to the button? Here is a cheat sheet for flexbox. [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)